# How to achieve multiple relations per database column in a RDBMS

Tags: schema, relational-database, rdbms, database-schema

I have a table A with column, 'properties'.  I have another table B with columns name, description. Is there any way in a RDBMS to have a schema where A.properties can point to multiple records in table B? For example:

```
A.properties --> [<B instance#1>, <B instance#2>, ...]
```

Can this be done? Is there a conventional and/or elegant way to do it?

I don't want to resort to NoSQL if I don't have to...and even then from what I've read, it is not possible to have relations in NoSQL (at least for MongoDB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is quite normal. One way would be to put the primary key of A in a column in B. The other way is to create a third, 'linking' table that links A with multiple Bs.